# How to access Audit Logs using 'SNOWFLAKE' shared DB in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, audit-logging

While exploring Snowflake documentation on Audit Logging (**user login history, object creation/deletion, query execution history etc**), I found the below information.

[image]

But in my trail account, I didn't find any shared DB with name **'SNOWFLAKE'**.

Would apreciate if someone can throw more light on this feature.

Neeraj

Comment: In the same documentation, there is a note: 

"By default, only account administrators (users with the ACCOUNTADMIN role) can access the SNOWFLAKE database and schemas within the database, or perform queries on the views; however, privileges on the database can be granted to other roles in your account to allow other users to access the objects. For more details, see Enabling Account Usage for Other Roles (in this topic)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the role in right upper corner is not sufficient. Yo uneed to change the role in the context.

After that, 'SNOWFLAKE' shared DB will be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose the 'ACCOUNTADMIN' role in the context of your session to see that database.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the ACCOUNTADMIN role in the context to access the SNOWFLAKE database.

Alternatively, As accountadmin, you can grant the privilege for viewing the data to other users as below.

Grant imported privileges on database snowflake to ; -- where  is an existing/new role granted to